# WordPress localization wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, dynamic-languages

i cannot set my theme's language to my language..

i've translated the needed field and set the mo + po file in 'wp-content/languages' folder
changed the field in wp-config.php file to my language - define('WPLANG', 'it_IT');

but still all the field in the theme are in english.. what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the language files in your theme directory?

The language files are in the default theme if you need them, or you can get them from here; http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Localization

It might also be worth reading this page with regard to localisation of themes & plugins when you're running more than one language; http://blog-en.icanlocalize.com/installing-wordpress-for-multiple-language-blogs/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins-with-gettext/

Finally I don't know if you're aware but theres a stack exchange specific to wordpress which you'll find more answers on than here; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just to be clear, im trying to translate the theme and not the hole wordpress system

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. When you mentioned wp-config I just assumed a global system change rather than theme specific. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this section of the 'How to': http://codex.wordpress.org/Files_For_Direct_Translation

As well as that there are some things that are not covered and need to manually translate.

But what you have done above does sound right for the rest.

Comment: im trying to translate the theme. the theme is already ready for localization.. i traslated to my language everything by its fields and put the mo+po files in its place.. after all of that, its still in english..